# C++ Deep-copy of a class with assignment operator

Tags: c++

If I had a overloaded assignment operator that need to deep-copy a class, how would I go about doing it?
 class Person contains a Name class

```
Person& Person::operator=(Person& per){
if (this==&per){return *this;}
// my attempt at making a deep-copy but it crashes  
this->name = *new Name(per.name);
}
```

in the name class copy-constructor and assignment operator

```
Name::Name(Name& name){

if(name.firstName){
firstName = new char [strlen(name.firstName)+1];
strcpy(firstName,name.firstName);
}

Name& Name::operator=(Name& newName){
if(this==&newName){return *this;}

if(newName.firstName){
firstName = new char [strlen(newName.firstName)+1];
strcpy(firstName,newName.firstName);

return *this;
}
```

Comment: First of all assignment and copy constructor take `const X&`and not just `X&`. Second, what is the type of `name` ? `Name&` ?  If yes, it won't work. If no, do not use `new` cause you have a leak.

Comment: Uee copy and swap Idiom : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leverage the existing copy constructor, destructor, and added `swap()` function:

```
Name& Name::operator= (Name other) {
    this->swap(other);
    return *this;
}
```

All copy assignments I'm implementing look like this implementation. The missing `swap()` function is also trivial to write:

```
void Name::swap(Name& other) {
    std::swap(this->firstName, other.firstName);
}
```

Likewise for `Person`.